# general security questions " potential hackers where my computer is."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, security, iis, ping

Does visual studio open any ports?

> I know it runs its own web-server (or IIS).  The reason I ask is that I just went to steve gibson's **"probe my ports"** site, and it indicated that my computer responds to '**pings**', which is says is a bad thing, because it tells potential hackers where my computer is.

Comment: For web applications, Visual Studio, by default, will use IIS Express which will use a random port. Whilst this port is open internally for you to develop your web application, it is blocked to external access.

Comment: It's unlikely that Visual Studio is responding to ping. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To disable PING you should block incoming ICMP packets on your firewall. However the gibson test might as well be for your router and not your computer since they use the IP you use to reach their site.

PING just tells if the computer is up and reachable from the internet. It doesn't tell anybody where your computer is. A simple traceroute might point to your current internet provider which is close enough to know where your computer is and there is no way to block that. You can check for open ports using nmap from another machine or an online service like gibsons or http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.portscan-test.html.

Comment: oops ! I can't upvote to this answer. Sorry dude. i will wait more answers

Comment: never mind the upvote - just block ICMP and re run the test to see if it gives you the same message again.